# How to sum grid column in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I have the grid like below. Can anybody tell me how to sum all the grid columns and display  them in the grid row

e.g

```
      Month   Achieve Target 

      Jan     3000     4000
      Feb     2000     5000

   **Total    5000     9000**   need to add total row in grid
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can use the [Ext.grid.feature.Summary](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Summary)
- [Here is an example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid/group-summary-grid.html) from the official docs

Post some of your code if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you can programatically calculate de sum, max, min, avg of a store column like this:

store.sum('yourColumn');